# Updating table when browser is closed in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've tried this code.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    return "You haven't logout your account. Do you want to leave without logout? ";    
}
</script >

<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
  <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">My Php File</a>
</body>
```

The output will be

```
   Are you sure want to leave this page?

 *Leave on this page     * Stay on this page
```

There are two options on above. Now, if I choose the Leave on page, how can I execute my php file? I mean, I want to update my table when I choose "Leave on this page".

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way of doing that which would guarantee you that the request was sent correctly in all major browsers.

One option would be sending ajax request in your `myFunction`, however, then you're risking that it won't get sent (the website will be left before your request will be successfuly sent).

The better option (although not widely supported) is to use [Beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon). This would perfectly suit your needs, I believe, however it is not supported by Safari and Internet Explorer at the moment.

Comment: I was actually making simple chatroom that detects all the users online and all user offlline in a page to be displayed. I don't have any idea if the user does not want or accidentally close the browser. I coudn't update my database. But base on your answer. It does not help me. hard to understand.

Comment: Then for this I would recommend you to make the user ping a server every few seconds letting it know that the user is still online. If the user fails to send any request within some time frame, then consider him being offline/leaving the page.

Comment: Any sample codes or link for reference. Codes the better to be understood.

Comment: Simply use `$.ajax` to make the request and `setInterval` to repeat the request every few seconds. On the server, check who is sending the request (in the request you can send a username, that way you know who is pinging). When somebody is trying to get people who are online, send only those people, who sent any request within last, say, 5 seconds, the rest will be considered as offline.

Comment: Would it not be easier to just use a ccustom  live session?